# Using Conditional Tags to restrict something to 1 user?

Tags: widgets, conditional-tags, content-restriction

I am using the following widget

http://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic/

This allows me to restrict widgets using [WP Conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags).

What I want is to restrict one widget to only 2 users.

This works for one user `current_user_can('level_10')` but gives access to all other level_10's (none atm) and not the other user.

How can I restrict this to just 2 users? I tried `is_author( '4' )` but didn't seem to pick it up (think it's just for author pages)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I display a user specific content?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14445/how-do-i-display-a-user-specific-content)

Comment: Your link is for a different plugin and does user roles, not specific users. I am looking for conditional code which works for 2 users who are different roles to work in the widget-logic plugin.

Comment: actually it does do specific users, but doesn't seem to work on widgets.. only posts or pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I **don't** know the plugin, but with a rapid eye on it, it seems that what you want is not, but you can rely on **widget_content filter** fired by the plugin you are using.

So, in your theme `function.php` put:

```
if ( function_exists('widget_logic_redirected_callback') )
   add_filter('widget_content', 'my_widget_for_user', 10, 2);

function my_widget_for_users ($widget_content, $widget_id) {
   $allowed_users = array('username1', 'username2');
   $restricted_widgets = array('widget_id_1', 'widget_id_2');
   global $current_user;
   get_currentuserinfo();
   if ( in_array($widget_id, $restricted_widgets) && ( empty($current_user->user_login) || ! in_array($current_user->user_login, $allowed_users) ) ) {
      $widget_content = '';
   }
   return $widget_content;
}
```

Doing so, if there is no user logged or the user is not an allowed one the widget is *technically* displayed but with **no content** so you will see... nothing.